# Can a CDI bean or JSF Managed bean implement any custom interface

Tags: jsf, cdi

Is it ok to implement other custom interfaces for a CDI or JSF session scoped bean.

Comment: Why do you suppose it isn't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is. And it's even desired in the case of `CDI` because you can have an interface which represents some service and than have multiple implementations of this service. Each implementation can have it's own [qualifier](http://java.dzone.com/articles/define-cdi-qualifier) and can be injected into the client by this qualifier, thus hiding it's actual implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, managed bean can implement custom interface.